# Is the skin on cashew nuts edible?

Tags: food-safety

In e.g. Viet Nam they seem to usually sell cashew nuts with the skin still on. Is the skin edible?

Viet Nam:

[image]

Most other countries where I've had cashew nuts:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Cashew nut shells are inedible and toxic, and are not commonly sold to consumers in most countries because they contain oils that can [cause dermatitis and allergic reactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cashew#Toxicity) similar to poison ivies.

Cashew skins are not as toxic but may still contain traces of the same chemicals and oils present in the shell, these may also leach through to the nut surface itself. It may cause mild to severe allergic reactions as [witnessed by some people in this post](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-eat-cashews-with-its-brownish-skin-on).

Raw cashew nuts are usually sold shelled, skinless, and treated to remove any left over chemicals, and don't usually reach consumers with skin.

[Heat mostly removes or denatures urushiol](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/are-cashews-poisonous#bottom-line), the main chemical responsible for their toxicity, so roasted or cooked cashew nuts are generally regarded as safe to eat even with skin on, though some prefer to remove it by flaking off between the fingers for taste or texture reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The skin is bitter and not meant to be eaten. If the cashews are roasted then they can be easily peeled off with your fingers

Comment: So in Viet Nam everyone always peels off the skin first?

Answer (score -1):

The first time I saw them like that was in a bulk bin in a supermarket in Israel. I tried them, really liked them.

They're very hard to find in Canada, but I like them so much that I mail-order them. I like them because I like the skins.

I've eaten a cupful at a time more than once.

No known harm has come to me from doing that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).